Does libpng have an upper limit on image width?
I am converting large raw data to image files using Ubuntu Linux. Works fine up to and including 1,000,000 pixels wide. Over this, eg 1,000,001, I get an error:
libpng warning: Image width exceeds user limit in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
Aborted (core dumped)
Just wondering if there is a test in libpng if(width > 1000000) error
Thanks
All works well up to 1000000 limit and no problems with memory.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looks like it might well have if the situation is as you describe. Try debugging into the code and look for a suspicious constant. Sourcecode is available... You might get a better authoritative  answer on the libPNG mailing list  if it still exists.

Please ensure your question is a [mcve]. You give no indication of how you are trying to do this...
